# Given a metric over the basis of a vector space, is the norm unique?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(e_i) = e_1,e_2,\cdots$ be a countable basis of a vector space $X$. Let $d(e_i, e_j)$ be a metric over $(e_i)$. Is it possible to have two different normed vector spaces $(X_1, \| \cdot \|_1)$ and $(X_2, \| \cdot \|_2)$, such that $(e_i) \subset X_1 \subset X$, $(e_i) \subset X_2 \subset X$, and $\| e_i - e_j \|_1 = \| e_i - e_j \|_2 = d(e_i, e_j)$ for all $i, j$?

To be clear, here $X_1 = \{ x \in X: \| x \|_1 < +\infty \}$ and $X_2 = \{ x \in X: \| x \|_2 < +\infty \}$. I want to know whether the norm that interpolates a metric over the basis, if it exists, must be unique.

Comment: If $(e_i)$ is a basis for $X$, and $X_1$ is a vector space containing $(e_i)$ and contained in $X$, don't we get $X_1=X$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Question updated.

Comment: I'm still confused. If $X_1$ contains $(e_i)$, then it contains every linear combination of the $e_i$, so it contains $X,$ no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is possible to have two different norms inducing the same metric. Take $X=c_{00}$ the space of sequences that are eventually zero. The sequences $e_n\in c_{00}$ that are zero everywhere except the $n$-th slot form a Hamel basis of $c_{00}$. Consider the norm $\|(x_n)\|_\alpha:=\sup_n|x_n|$. Under this norm, $\|e_i-e_j\|_\alpha=1$. Consider also the norm $\|(x_n)\|_\beta:=\frac{1}{2}\sum_n|x_n|$. Under this norm, $\|e_i-e_j\|_\beta=1$. In other words, both norms induce the discrete metric on the set $\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$.

In our example, $X_1=X_2=X$ (using your notation).